# CakePHP query array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am running this query using CakePHP:

```
$total = $this->Lapse->query("select sum(unix_timestamp(stop) - unix_timestamp(start)) from lapses where id = ".$lastId."");
```

And i get back this array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sum(unix_timestamp(stop) - unix_timestamp(start))] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

So my variable holds this: `$updateVal = $total[0][0][0];`

Which isn't the prettiest, is there a way i can simplify this OTT array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `find()` method passing a custom `fields` option?:

```
$this->Lapse->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('sum(unix_timestamp(stop) - unix_timestamp(start)) as elapsed_time'),
  'conditions' => array('Lapse.id' => $lastId),
));
```

The returned array is prettier than the one you're getting, although it's not prettier than `elapsed_time` being an actual model property.

Another solution would be to set `elapsed_time` as a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) within the model:

```
class Lapse extends AppModel {
  ...

  public $virtualFields = array(
    'elapsed_time' => 'sum(unix_timestamp(Lapse.stop) - unix_timestamp(Lapse.start)',
  );

  ...
}
```

Then `elapsed_time` acts as a model property and would be returned as `$updateVal['Lapse']['elapsed_time']` in every `find()` call.